# What is the resistance of an ohmic sphere with surface potential $\phi_0\cos\theta$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-current, electrical-resistance, classical-electrodynamics

I'm trying to find the volumetric density of current in the interior of a sphere (made of ohmic material) with radius $a$, conductivity $g$ and surface potential $\phi=\phi_0cos\theta$.

This is the way I thought I could solve it:

First, it seems to me that the electric field should have only a $z$ component since the potential is symmetric with respect to the azimutal angle and increases when we move along the $z$ axis, having values $\phi=-\phi_0$ when $z=-a$ and $\phi=\phi_0$ when $z=a$. (Is this assumption correct?)
Secondly, I would compute the value of the resistance $R$ of the sphere using the formula $R=\frac{\Delta L}{gS}$ for a cylindric conductor of section $S$ and length $\Delta L$. In order to do that I have to sum up the resistance of all the cylinders of infinitesimal lenght $dz$, section $S(z)=\pi(a^2-z^2)$ and resistance $dR(z)=\frac{dz}{\pi g(a^2-z^2)}$. So, I would have: $$R=\int_{-a}^a\frac{dz}{\pi g(a^2-z^2)}$$
Then I would use Omh's law fo find $I$ (using that $\Delta\phi=2\phi_0$), and finally I would obtain the volumetric density of current $J$ as a function of $z$ using the formula $J=\frac{I}{S(z)}$.

Now, the problem is that the integral for the resiastance diverges, which would imply $J=0$ and it doesn't seem to be correct. What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: Why the downvote? It would be much more helpful to give me a suggestion on how to improve my question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46561/discussion-on-question-by-eliana-what-is-the-resistance-of-an-ohmic-sphere-with).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really solve this problem using $z$-slices, disks, because not all of the current passes through every disk. If all of the current had to pass through every disk then the resistance will be infinite because of the need to pass finite current through the points with zero cross sectional area at opposite sides of the sphere. Instead, you'll need to add cylindrical shell conductors in parallel. When resistors are in parallel, the conductance, $1/R$, adds. The conductance of a cylindrical shell with height $2z$, radius $r$, and width $\operatorname{d}r$ is:
$$\operatorname{d}\left(\frac{1}{R}\right) = \frac{g 2\pi r \operatorname{d}r}{2z}.$$ Because the cylindars are contained in a sphere, the half-height, $z$ is given by the equation: $$z = \sqrt{a^2 - r^2}.$$ So the total conductance is:
$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{R} &= \pi g\int_0^a \frac{r}{\sqrt{a^2 - r^2}}\operatorname{d}r \Rightarrow \\
R &= \frac{1}{\pi g a}. \end{align} $$ This, at least, will be the resistance if $\Phi(r=a) = \phi_0 \operatorname{sgn}(z)$ on the surface of the sphere. For your situation the need to use $\mathbf{J} = \sigma \mathbf{E}$ may be unavoidable.

Comment: I was thinking similarly but I think this cannot be correct with this potential boundary condition. For adding conductances of the cylindrical shells to obtain the total conductance and thus the total resistance you need to have  the same potential difference for all  contributing cylindrical shell conductances. I see a problem here to define a total resistance or conductance here.

Comment: Right, and I added the caveat in the last sentence. The total resistance is likely taken as $2\phi_0 / I_{\mathrm{tot}}$, with $I_{\mathrm{tot}}$ calculated from $\mathbf{J}$ from the continuous version of Ohm's law.

Comment: Yes, but this last potential sign assumption contradicts the original boundary condition.

Comment: @ Eliana - Are you sure that a total resistance is asked for here?

Comment: @freecharly no, actually it was asked to find the electric potential and the volumetric density of current inside the sphere but I thought the way of doing so was finding the resistance first and then using the diference of potential to find the current and then the density of current

Comment: To define a resistance you need a definite potential difference at the leads where the current is entering and exiting and the total current.

Comment: If $E=\phi_0/a$, then $J = g\phi_0/a$. Thus $I_{\mathrm{tot}} = \pi g \phi_0 a$. If we define $R = 2\phi_0 / I_{\mathrm{tot}} = 2 / (\pi g a).$ The reason for using $V=2\phi_0$ in Ohm's law is because that's the difference between the top and bottom of the sphere.

Comment: @Eliana - This relaxes the situation completely. As I said, in my opinion no total resistance can be defined here. The solution of the Laplace is extremely  simple, just a vertical homogeneous field which gives you a simple homogeneous current density. Thank heavens, no resistance is needed.

Comment: @ Dean Leake - Yes, this sounds good because it is dimensionally a resistance with the given parameters. But it is not a resistance in a physical sense because there are no  current leads with this potential difference.

Comment: @ Dean Lake - Nevertheless, you solved the problem beautifully with this really surprising result of a constant vertical homogeneous current density.

Comment: Not necessarily, @freecharly. You can get at resistance without direct reference to Ohm's law. You can use $P = I^2R$ to define another resistance. The heating per unit volume in this case will be $\mathbf{J}\cdot \mathbf{E} = g \phi_0^2 / a^2$, giving a total power output of $P_{\mathrm{tot}} = g\phi_0^2/a^2 \times 4\pi a^3/3 = 4 \pi g\phi_0^2 a/3$. Dividing by total current squared gives:  $R_{\mathrm{eff}} = 4 \pi g\phi_0^2 a/3 / (\pi a^2 g \phi_0/a)^2 = 4/(3\pi ga)$.

Comment: What I think is encouraging about the power definition is that if you imagined constructing a device that sets this situation up that has no resistive losses in the setup, it cannot avoid supplying a current $I_{\mathrm{tot}}$, and it cannot avoid at least supplying power $P_{\mathrm{tot}}$.

Comment: @ Dean Lake - Just for curiosity. With this new surface potential boundary condition ϕ0·sign(z) do you still get the required homogeneous vertical field solution inside the sphere?

Comment: No, for a surface potential on a sphere like that you get a different potential. It's a standard exercise to expand the function $\operatorname{sgn}(\cos \theta)$ in a [Legendre series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendrePolynomial.html), and add the appropriate power of $r$ to each term to find the potential.

Comment: The power definition P=I^2·R, however, also contains Ohm's law V=I·R so there is implicitly a voltage  V across this resistor.

Comment: @Sean Lake - Thanks, this was a very entertaining session. And I also learned something new.